# Perl: Formatted output to email body

Tags: perl

I am generating a formatted text output using perl's format syntax, then I slurp the entire output to a scalar variable and when I send this as email body, entire text looses its formatting , funny thing is when I copy and paste the received emails body to a text editor (notepad) it pastes as original formatted text.
I tried different encoding but nothing helped sending as html is even worse.
Any pointers that could resolve this issue would be much appreciated.
For email I am using MIME::Lite and  Net::SMTP.
Thanks
/G

Edit: Here is the code I used to send the email:

```
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From    => 'username@domain.com',
    To      => 'username2@domain.com',
    Cc      => '',
    Subject => 'Helloooooo,!',
    Type    => 'multipart/related',
);

$msg->attach(
    Type => 'text/plain charset=ANSI',
    Data => encode("Windows-1250", $data)
);

$msg->send('smtp', 'smtp.domain', Debug=>0);
```

Comment: Are you sending in text/html format?

Comment: I already tried  text/html or text/plain , with html like i said its even worse

Comment: Please show the code you're using so we can help, without having to write a solution for you from scratch.

Comment: Is only the *displayed* formatting off? Is the mail source code all right? Can you show us the exact email you receive (sans unneccessary headers)?

Comment: Here is code I am using to sent email$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
        From     => 'username@domain.com',
        To       => 'username2@domain.com',
        Cc       => '',
        Subject  => 'Helloooooo,!',
        Type     => 'multipart/related'
    );
   $msg->attach(
        Type => ' text/plain charset=ANSI',
        Data =>  encode("Windows-1250", $data)
    );
    $msg->send('smtp','smtp.domain',Debug=>0)

Comment: Try to replace `Type => ' text/plain charset=ANSI'` with `Type => 'text/plain'` be careful with spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text/plain charset=ANSI
```

should be

```
text/plain; charset=Windows-1250
```

or

```
text/plain; charset=cp1250
```

(Not sure what is recognized by mail programs, but ANSI is not an encoding.)

But the real problem (based on info provided in your latest comment) has nothing to do with mail headers. It's simply a font selection issue. In notepad, you use a non-proportional font (e.g. Courier New). That means that every character in the font takes the same real-estate on the screen.

10 "l" and 10 "m": `llllllllllmmmmmmmmmm`
10 "m" and 10 "l": `mmmmmmmmmmllllllllll`

Your email reader, on the other hand, uses a proportional font (e.g. Ariel, Times New Roman). In such fonts, narrower characters (e.g. "l") use fewer horizontal pixels than wider characters (e.g. "m").

10 "l" and 10 "m": llllllllllmmmmmmmmmm
10 "m" and 10 "l": mmmmmmmmmmllllllllll

Solution: Change your email reader's font, or change your payload to a format in which you can specify the font (HTML).

Comment: I tried both but no luck , I took a screen shot of actual and what I see in email , it seems that difference is due to character spacing , meaning "-" is much smaller in email than in the text file

Comment: ikegami that was very good suggestion. Eventually I just changed my  e-mail client settings  in my case it was outlook 2010 , to read text emails in Courier New. And now it displays in perfect format.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully use this construct:

```
# Convert the data to HTML.
my $html = $data;
$html =~ s/&/&amp;/g;
$html =~ s/</&lt;/g;
$html =~ s/>/&gt;/g;

# Add header and formatting.
$html = <<"__EOI__";
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Helloooooo,!</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>$html</pre>
</body>
</html>
__EOI__

# Convert to bytes.
$html = encode("UTF-8", $html);

# Send it.
my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
        From    => 'username@domain.com',
        To      => 'username2@domain.com',
        Subject => 'Helloooooo,!',
        Type    => 'text/html',
        Data    => $html,
);
$msg->send();
```

I don't use $msg->attach() like you do because it's not needed in this case.

Comment: As the OP mentioned, what you posted doesn't work. It loses all formatting, and it would misinterpret certain sequences of characters (starting with `&`, `<` or `>`). You also removed the necessary encoding step. I've added all of these missing components.