# sprintf format and print inconsistencies whilst creating fixed width column

Tags: perl, printf

(I have already cross posted onto another site and will update either with the solution but so far struggling with an answer)

> > > > > > 19th Dec 2013 7:06pm PT --- I found the solution and I updated below.

I am outputting two items of data per line. The first column of data is not fixed length, and I want the second item of data to be correctly aligned in the same position each time so I am using sprintf to format the data and then mail out the data

The print command output illustrates that the data is formatted correctly.

Yet, when the output in my email is different, the alignment is all wrong.

I initially thought it was the mailer (MIME::Lite) program but I am not sure it is.

Reason why I think that is because I using eclipse Perl environment, when I look at the debug variable list, I see that the strings are padded out exactly like the output in my email, yet the print statement shows the data correctly aligned!!!

Please help me understand what is going on here and how to fix it.

```
use MIME::Lite;
$smtp = "mailserver";
$internal_email_address = 'myemailaddess';
$a = sprintf ("%-60s %-s\n", "the amount for Apple is ","34");
$b = sprintf ("%-60s %-s\n", "the amount for Lemons is", "7");
print $a;
print $b;
$c = $a.$b;
mailer( $internal_email_address,"issue", $c);

sub mailer {
    my ( $addr, $subj, $output ) = @_;

    print "$_\n" for $addr;
    print "$_\n" for $subj;
    print "$_\n" for $output;

    $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
        From    => 'xxxx',
        To      => $addr,
        Subject => $subj,
        Data    => $output
    );

    MIME::Lite->send( 'smtp', $smtp, Timeout => 60 );
    eval { $msg->send };
    $mailerror = "Status: ERROR email - MIME::Lite->send failed: $@\n" if $@;
    if ( $mailerror eq '' ) {
        $status = "Status: Mail sent\n";
    }
    else {
        $status = $mailerror;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue: `print "$_\n" for $addr;` doesn't really make sense (you're looping through a single item); use `print "$addr\n";` instead.

Comment: Is a cross post not allowed?  I found that there seems to be more solutions on stackoverflow than perlmonks?

Comment: [Cross posting is allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22657/is-it-wrong-to-ask-the-same-question-elsewhere), but it is generally considered polite to say that you are doing so. When you get an answer on either site, please post it to the other one so people don't waste time solving a problem that's already been solved.

Comment: I certainly will do so.

Comment: Is your mail client (the one displaying the email) showing using a fixed-width font or a variable-width font? Have you looked at the raw email to see whether it contains what you expect?

Comment: I am using outlook 2010,  the view source has been disabled so it is hard to tell. I disabled all formatting in outlook and it made no difference. Regarding fonts, its set to use one font and one size only.

Comment: What font would that be?

Comment: Hi Michael, I am using Calibri Regular 11.

Comment: I think its definitely some kind of weird formatting issue,  I am wondering if this is an encoding issue of some kind.

Comment: SO, if I take the email output, throw it into a notepad document, the doc perfectly aligns as expected. 

So, do I need to encode the mime data somehow to send a plain text file to outlook is the direction I am going to look into next.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. It turned out that the font was causing this after all, a few users suggested it and I had looked at the wrong part of outlook for the font I was using for emails received.   I needed to use a non proportional font, this link helped. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588021/perl-formatted-output-to-email-body

Comment: Further update for anyone else caught up in this and not looking to change the client outlook font.  I used sprintf and wrapped my string with a HTML <pre> </pre>  and set the Type    =>'text/html , produced a perfect output using non proportional fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = sprintf ("%-10s %-s\n", "the amount for Apple is ","34");
```

The argument `"the amount for Apple is"` is too long for the format specifier `%-10s`, so the actual amount of space used for that argument will be the length of the string.

You could use a format specifier with a larger value (e.g., `%-25s`) that can accomodate any value you're likely to apply to it.

Or if you want `sprintf` to truncate the argument at 10 characters, use the format specifier `%-10.10s`.

Comment: Mob,  Thank you so much for your reply., I just tried changing the value to be larger than the string and the same issue applies.  I will update the post with the updated size I tried.